# Can we delete reference cycle object and free its memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, garbage-collection

I read different articles about garbage collection. They say that we need `gc` module to clean the reference cycle object. But can we do the cleaning by simply using del?

For example, if I do the following, do I successfully free the memory of this reference cycle object? If yes, then why do we need `gc` module anyway? If not, then why not?

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]    
>>> x.append(x)    # create reference cycle
>>> print(x)
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
>>> sys.getrefcount(x)
3


>>> del x[3]
>>> print(x)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> sys.getrefcount(x)
2
>>> del x    # reference count of x goes to 0!
```

Comment: Do you really want to *manually* clean up every reference cycle in an entire complex program? Do you really think you'd get it right?

Comment: I am just curious if it can be done theoretically. I never deal with garbage before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cpython is reference counted. When the object reference count goes to zero, it is deleted - and that's done inline with the code that caused the decrement. The garbage collector is there to handle the case where an object is unreachable but its reference count is not zero. Its not that every circular reference needs a garbage collection. It matters how that reference is unwound.

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
```

We created a list and bound it to `x`. The list itself is just an anonymous object in memory, but currently reachable by `x`. Lets call the actual object *the list*.

```
>>> x.append(x)    # create reference cycle
>>> print(x)
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
>>> sys.getrefcount(x)
3
```

At this point, *the list* has references from `x`, its own 4th element and the `getrefcount` parameter (which disappears when the function returns, leaving 2 references).

```
>>> del x[3]
```

`del` doesn't actually delete things. It unbinds objects. In that case, the list's `__delitem__` function is called unbinding *the list* from its own 4th element, leaving a single reference.

```
>>> del x
```

This time `del` unbinds *the list* from `x` and removes `x` from the namespace. The reference count went to zero and *the list* was deleted. The garbage collector was never envolved.

Now lets mix it up.

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]    
>>> x.append(x)    # create reference cycle
```

We have 2 references to *the list*. But this time just

```
>>> del x
```

`del` unbinds *the list* from `x` and decrements its reference count to 1. That's not enough to delete *the list*. Now we have a problem. *the list* is no longer assigned to any variable that we can get to. Its not in `x` because `x` doesn't exist any more. But its still in memory. That is what the garbage collector attempts to fix.

We can't just use `del` because there is no variable to do the `del` on.